# How can I avoid duplicating this grid config code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, devexpress

I have the following code that is used in a Razor view to configure grid settings for a DevExpress GridView MVC extension. All is good with the code, but now I wish to do data exports from the grid, which require the same configuration code on the 'server', i.e. upstream of the view. I could quite easily do this and provide a GridSettings property on my view model, if it were not for the required access to the `WebViewPage<TModel>.ViewContext` property.

Right now I am using a really ugly workaround and passing `ViewContext` back into the controller from the view; the controller then builds the grid settings. Needless to say the view calling a method on the controller is rather smelly.

```
settings.Columns.Add(column =>
                        {
                            column.Caption = "#";
                            column.SetDataItemTemplateContent(c =>
                                                                    {
                                                                        ViewContext.Writer.Write(
                                                                            Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new {id = DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "Id")}) + "&nbsp" +
                                                                            Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new {id = DataBinder.Eval(c.DataItem, "Id")},
                                                                                            new {onclick = "return confirm('Do you really want to delete this record? [Just say no!]')"})
                                                                            );
                                                                    });
                            column.SetHeaderTemplateContent(c => ViewContext.Writer.Write(Html.ActionLink("New", "Create")));
                            column.Settings.AllowDragDrop = DefaultBoolean.False;
                            column.Settings.AllowSort = DefaultBoolean.False;
                            column.Width = 70;
                        });
settings.Columns.Add("RefNum", "Emp. No.");
```

Comment: Bug: "&nbsp" should be "&nbsp;"

Comment: @usr, Funny, I never noticed that bug, thanks, because Chrome inserts a space and even without a space default styling spaces the `<a>` tags just enough to not notice.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is necessary to have **only** the **"Name"** property of the exported GridViewSettings object on both the PartialView and Controller sides.

The GridView's PartialView should also be wrapped with a form.

See [this](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3898) example in the DX code library and [this](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q396028.aspx) thread.

It is possible to specify shared GridViewSettings on the Controller side within a static object (like in [this](http://demos.devexpress.com/MVC/GridView/Export) demo).

Comment: with only `Name` on both sides, how do I specify columns and formats for the export?

Comment: I am using that DX demo, but it doesn't include hyperlinks in a column, which have to  be created in the view, not the controller. The column in my example code doesn't work in the demo you link to.